# Find all CSS styles used on website

Tags: css, dotnetnuke, html-parsing

I have a DotNetNuke skin that has a single CSS file over 3,500 lines long. It contains styles for YUI, Telerik, Cluetip as well as the actual customisation of the site. The old developers just kept adding styles and never cleaned up the old unused ones.

I want to cleanup the file and get it to a more managable size. I first thought about scanning through the code base but this is 5,500 files with a mixture of CSS applied in the .aspx, .ascx and .cs files as well as jQuery aplying styles sometimes from generated code and sometimes from js files. Some styles are applied with class selectors and others with id selectors.

Is there a way I can easily check just which styles the website actually needs across all of its pages? Is there some crawler that could do this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For firefox there is an add-in called [dust-me-selectors](http://www.sitepoint.com/dustmeselectors/). If you provide a sitemap, it will find all unused css styles.

Comment: Really great tool, just what I needed, and another good reason to sort out my sitemap!

Comment: dust-me-selectors -- Cool been looking for something along these lines

Comment: Love it! and for Chrome `Properties > Tools > Developer Tools
Click the Audits tab, and then run the test` works as well

Answer (score 1):

If you run dust-me-selectors, remember to run it in every page of your website so you don't delete any styles that are actually used.

Comment: If you give a sitemap, it will spider all those pages.