# all css classes in page using js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i want to be able to get all the class names of all css files on the page.
Is there any existing possibility or do i have to read it and parse it by myself. Isn´t there any api of the browser?

Comment: Please clarify: Are you asking how to find out the names of all **HTML classes** that are mentioned in **class selectors** that form all or part of the **selectors** for all **rule sets** in all the CSS that is loaded from **external files**? (I suspect this is only partially right).

Comment: Do you mean all `class="..."` names?

Comment: Or all the values in the `class` attributes on `<link>` elements that are `rel=stylesheet`?

Comment: If you want all classes applied to elements in the page, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795735/find-all-css-styles-used-on-website).

Comment: sorry for late reply, no, i need all available classes in all <link> files and all onpage style rules, not just that are placed in html elements like class="..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is maybe a dulplicate request of this? [How do you read CSS rule values with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324486/how-do-you-read-css-rule-values-with-javascript)

```
function getStyle(className) {
    var classes = document.styleSheets[0].rules || document.styleSheets[0].cssRules
    for(var x=0;x<classes.length;x++) {
        if(classes[x].selectorText==className) {
                (classes[x].cssText) ? alert(classes[x].cssText) : alert(classes[x].style.cssText);
        }
    }
}
getStyle('.test')
```

Comment: Hej thank you, it´s not the exact answer, but it told me what i needed to now. I needed the document.styleSheets -> rules -> selectorText. If you want, you can change your code so I get all selectorText items in one list. +1