# Get defined CSS classes by pattern

Tags: javascript, css

Is there any possiblity get all defined CSS classes matching a pattern?

For example if you have some CSS rules defined like:

```
.my-custom-class-one {}
.my-custom-class-two {}
.my-custom-class-three {}
```

I'd like to have something like:

```
console.log( getClassNamesByPattern('my-custom-class-*') );
```

returning a list of the matching classes:

```
[ 'my-custom-class-one', 'my-custom-class-two', 'my-custom-class-three' ]
```

There is no markup matching those selectors (yet). Actually that's what i'd like to create...

I thought maybe something like `getComputedStyles` would do the trick, but since it expects an  element, which doesn't exists, it doesn't seem to be of much use...

Comment: Are you using jquery on your site?  If so, then using a filter might be a solution for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following would be a solution:

CSS

```
.my-custom-class-one {}
.my-custom-class-two {}
.my-custom-class-three {}
```

JS

```
function getClassNamesByPattern(pattern) {
    var selectors = {};

    for (var i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++) {
        var classes = document.styleSheets[i].rules || document.styleSheets[i].cssRules;
        for (var x = 0; x < classes.length; x++) {
            if (undefined !== classes[x].selectorText && null !== classes[x].selectorText.match(new RegExp('\\.' + pattern.replace(/([^\s])\*/, '$1[^ ]+'), 'g'))) {
                selectors[classes[x].selectorText] = classes[x].selectorText;
            }
        }
    }

    return Object.keys(selectors);
}

console.log(getClassNamesByPattern('my-custom-class-*'));
```

as seen here [all css classes in page using js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5315033/all-css-classes-in-page-using-js)

...wondering how that might perform on pages with lots of style rules, though.

Comment: I would probably use something like: `classes[x].selectorText.match(new RegExp('\\.'+pattern.replace(/([^\s])\*/,'$1[^ ]+'),'g'))`

Comment: I suppose that check for the existence of `classes[x].selectorText` may be needed, since [not all CSSrule subtypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSRule?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FcssRule) have such property. Otherwise it's the only possible solution to find the CSS rules declared but not used by actual DOM elements, AFAIK.

Comment: @MarkResølved I've updated my comment as well - was flawed. Might want to change to the new version

Comment: Shouldn't you also loop through `document.styleSheets` instead of just checking the first one: `document.styleSheets[0]`?

Comment: This fails in Firefox with the error "Operation is Insecure". Firefox prevents cross-domain CSS traversal. If you need to find some custom CSS classes, you may need to restrict yourself to your own CSS, which this solution doesn't do.